# Is it possible to have conjunction of certain "favorite tags"?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-watching

In a [related post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8799/should-i-be-hesitant-to-answer-questions), it was suggested that I answer homework questions. However, there are still certain subjects I don't have a strong understanding of. And so I would like to know if it was possible to have one's favorite tags be (homework) AND (real-analysis), for example. This is just the highlighting of problems are more accurate. I have no complaints of the current system, I'm just wondering if it's possible.

**Update:** In case anyone finds this post in the future, [here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#searching) what I should have searched for at prior to posting this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the search to narrow down things. If you enter tags in the search search, for example:

> [homework] [real-analysis]

the result is questions from the intersection of the tags.

You can add more modifiers, `is:question`, limitation on score, with or without answers (or accepted answers) and so on.